# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. laravel 9

Tags: laravel, composer

buen día compañeros... estoy intentando hacer una pequeña aplicación con laravel version 9. tengo PHP 8.1 y ya instale composer. pero al momento de dar el comando para crear el proyecto me tira el error que puse en el titulo. ¿ me podrían ayudar? es la 1era vez que usare laravel y composer jeje.
cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

les adjunto la imagen de la consola. trabajo en windows.

[image]

y otros problemas más que me dio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya encontré el problema!... el problema era que quitaba el ; en las extensiones de php en la carpeta de xampp. pero no lo quite en otra carpeta de php.

D:xampp/php/php.ini
lo cambie aquí

pero no lo cambie en

D:php/php.ini

acá también tengo que quitar el ;

para los que se preguntan lo mismo la extensión que se debe habilitar es

extension=fileinfo
y
extension=intl

quitando el ; que esta al frente de cada una

;extension=fileinfo -> extension=fileinfo